# Make CollectionView and TableView height dynaimc

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

In the xib shown, I have a Collection View and a Table View. I wish to make their heights dynamic as there may be times when nothing shows for either view or else the height can be anything.

I was able to make the Collection View dynamic by not adding a height, but I have had to add the Table View and since then there is a missing constraints error for both components - `Need constraints for: Y position or height`

(All the other components in the xib have a fixed height)

[image]

Comment: row height is static for both ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I'm not sure what you mean. Where is that set?

Comment: i mean text/image insdie the rows of the table/collection is static like 100 or 200 ??

Comment: Yes - row height is static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to create two outlets for the height of the table and the collection , then according to number of rows do

```
 self.tableHeight.constant = 100 * numberOfTblRows
 self.collHeight.constant = 100 * numberOfCollRows
 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank-you. Now I just need to figure out the number of rows in the collection view as the width of each cell is dynamic.